# Руткит в Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, безопасность

Просканировал систему программой [Volatility](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility), нашел левые процессы.

Посоветуйте еще программы или команды для проверки.

**Вот список левых процессов:**

| Offset | Name | Pid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x0000000008016700 | 0?{??U | 5253 |
| 0x0000000049f75700 |  | 5659 |
| 0x0000000069e6dd40 |  | 745 |
| 0x000000006f1ec700 |  | 5683 |
| 0x000000007a87fb40 |  | 5683 |
| 0x00000000884ea700 | )?Hc???Hi??Mb?? | 2477 |
| 0x000000009745f700 |  | 2934 |

Comment: с помощью ps смотрите по pid, что за процесс. `lsof -p <pid>` покажет какие файлы открыты процессом. Но если это нормальный  руткит, то Вам будет говорить, что процесс не найден (хотя он мог просто завершится).  А ещё можно пойти в папку `/proc/<pid>` и попытаться понять, что к чему с процессом.
но самый лучший вариант - загрузится с лайв сиди и с него просканировать

Comment: тут стандартные методы не помогут, название первого процесса в таблице - 0?{??U (ты ноль). нужен более глубокий анализ, сомневаюсь что моих навыков хватит для блокировки, если учесть кто у меня в системе.

Comment: думаю, это просто утилита сломана:) Но линукс - это линукс. Грузитесь с лайв сиди и вычищайте. Даже самые "крутые" (а по факту - тупые) руткиты вряд ли справятся (если только в этом случае Вы не запустите их своими ручками)

Comment: да нет несломана. лайв сиди тоже не поможет, очаг в материнской плате.

Comment: как это "очаг в материнской плате"? оно что, биос/UEFI перепрошило?

Comment: @KoVadim, на плате столько микроконтроллеров и фирмварей, что подсадить вирус можно куда угодно. Разве для вас это открытие?! (Предупреждая следующие комментарии: нет, на всяких ARM, PowerPC и так далее дело в современном мире обстоит не лучше)

Comment: я верю, что можно сделать перепрошивку биоса и подобного, но только сильно-сильно-сильно сомневаюсь, что это случай автора вопроса.